# Laravel 8 parameters in middle of route not working on Linux OS, but working on macOS

Tags: laravel, jwt, laravel-8

I got an error with `Laravel framework` after upgrade from `v7 to v8` routes contains parameters on the middle of path like below example doesn’t working on server `(Linux OS)`, But works on local env `(macOS)`

```
Route::put('resources/{id}/publish', 'ResourceController@publish');
```

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Error>
        <Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
        <Message>Unsupported Authorization Type</Message>
        <ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName>
        <ArgumentValue>Bearer  token</ArgumentValue>
        <RequestId>someid</RequestId>
        <HostId>somehash</HostId>
    </Error>
```

When move the parameter at the end of route it works on both.

```
Route::put('resources/publish/{id}', 'ResourceController@publish');
```

**Update**

Route group begin with:

```
Route::resource('resources', 'ResourceController', ['index', 'store', 'show', 'update', 'destroy']);
```

Any help will be appreciated,

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us another routes, that contain `resources` keyword at the begining?

Comment: @MalkhaziDartsmelidze updated my answer with routes group resources

Answer (score 0):

Got the reason of this error and it doesn’t related to neither `Laravel` nor `JWT-Auth`,

It was `nginx` config with wrong `location` matching pattern to `proxy_pass` to S3.

So this `resources/{id}/publish` route matches wrongly with S3 `proxy_pass` and error thrown from S3 not laravel.